# PHP Pagination show first two pages and last two pages

Tags: php, pagination

I'm currently using the php pagination script below. The pagination displays six results per page with previous/next links. I was wondering if anyone might know what I could add so that the pagination also displays links to the first two pages and the last two pages? Like the pagination in this example page: http://www.winelog.net/wines/Oregon

```
$data=file("data.txt");
$pages=0;
foreach($data as $temp){
    $x=explode("|",$temp);
    if($x[0] > 0){
        $pages=$pages+1;
    }
}

if($_GET['p']){
    $page=$_GET['p'];
}

if($_GET['i']){
    $index=$_GET['i'];
}

if($index == "p"){
    $page=$page-1;
}
if($index == "n"){
    $page=$page+1;
}
if($page < 1){
    $page=1;
}
if($page  >  $pages){
    $page=$pages;
}
$line=$data[$page-1];
$fields=explode("|",$line);
```

The displayed navigation:

```
$show=6;
echo "<li><a href='?i=p&p=$page'>&#171; PREV</li></a>";

if($page-($show/2)  >  1){
    $temp=$page-$show;
    echo "<li><a href='?p=$temp'>...</li></a>";
}

if($page-($show/2) >= 1 && $page+($show/2) <= $pages){
    $start=$page-($show/2);
    $stop=$page+($show/2);
}

if($page-($show/2) < 1){
    $start=1;
    $stop=$show;
}

if($page+($show/2) > $pages){
    $start=$pages-$show;
    $stop=$pages;
}

for($i=$start; $i<=$stop; $i++){
    if($page==$i){
        echo "<li class='active'>$i</li></a>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<li><a href='?p=$i'>$i</li></a>";
    }
}

if($page+($show/2) < $pages){
    $temp=$page+$show;
    echo "<li><a href='?p=$temp'>...</li></a>";
}
echo "<li><a href='?i=n&p=$page'>NEXT &#187;</li></a>";
```

Comment: I would perhaps go the jquery way. Its simple and cleaner. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Comment: @Nikhil: Why??! You're creating a dependency on Javascript, the plugin will be slower and he'll presumably have to send all the data to the page - very slow, potentially. Stop pushing things to the client that don't have to be pushed there!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need to do.

First get a count of the number of 'pages' that there are.
If there are less than, say, 10 pages - output all the pages.

Otherwise:
Output from current page - 5 to current page + 5.
Before the output, put a 'First' button - page = 1
After the output, put a 'Last' button - page = total number of pages.

If you want a second-to-last button, just go page = total number of pages - 1, etc.

You might want to look into [Zend_Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.html) - You don't need to use the whole Zend Framework to use individual parts of it, it's designed so it can be pulled apart.

Comment: Please update the link to Zend_Paginator as it returns a well known ERROR 404 page...

Answer (score 1):

The full code of their pagination script is available for free @[Stranger Studios](http://www.strangerstudios.com/sandbox/pagination/diggstyle.php) There is a `php` and a `Perl` script available for download.

**Code PHP version:**

```
<?php
//function to return the pagination string
function getPaginationString($page = 1, $totalitems, $limit = 15, $adjacents = 1, $targetpage = "/", $pagestring = "?page=")
{       
    //defaults
    if(!$adjacents) $adjacents = 1;
    if(!$limit) $limit = 15;
    if(!$page) $page = 1;
    if(!$targetpage) $targetpage = "/";

    //other vars
    $prev = $page - 1;                                  //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                                  //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($totalitems / $limit);             //lastpage is = total items / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                              //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\"";
        if($margin || $padding)
        {
            $pagination .= " style=\"";
            if($margin)
                $pagination .= "margin: $margin;";
            if($padding)
                $pagination .= "padding: $padding;";
            $pagination .= "\"";
        }
        $pagination .= ">";

        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage$pagestring$prev\">� prev</a>";
        else
            $pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">� prev</span>";    

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . $counter . "\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage >= 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 3))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . $counter . "\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination .= "<span class=\"elipses\">...</span>";
                $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . $lpm1 . "\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . $lastpage . "\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . "1\">1</a>";
                $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . "2\">2</a>";
                $pagination .= "<span class=\"elipses\">...</span>";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . $counter . "\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination .= "...";
                $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . $lpm1 . "\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . $lastpage . "\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . "1\">1</a>";
                $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . "2\">2</a>";
                $pagination .= "<span class=\"elipses\">...</span>";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (1 + ($adjacents * 3)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . $counter . "\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $targetpage . $pagestring . $next . "\">next �</a>";
        else
            $pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
        $pagination .= "</div>\n";
    }

    return $pagination;

}
?>
```

Change the code to fit your needs and add some `CSS`.

There are a lot of questions about pagination, I hope this is helpful to users who in need of a pagination script..

Answer (score 0):

The link to the winelog site is broken. Hence, I couldn't see the sample you are interested in.
I have written a pagination script in PHP which shows two adjacent pages to the active page, i.e.

```
< 1  2  3 4  5 >  // 3 being the active page

< 1  2  3  4 >  // 2 being the active page
```

Here is the code:

```
/* set total records */
$total_records = 26;  // this is the total count of values in an array or query results from the database

/* set records per page */
$records_per_page = 5;

/* calculate total pages */
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $records_per_page);

/* get and set value for current page */
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $current_page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $current_page = 1;
}

/* calculate and set previous and next page values */
$previous = $current_page - 1;
$next = $current_page + 1;

/* set start page value */
$start_page = 1;

/* set number of pages to display to the left */
/* maximum value should be 4 */
$pages_to_left = 2;

/* set number of pages to display to the right */
/* maximum value should be 4 */
$pages_to_right = 2;

/* show previous pages to the left */
if ($current_page <= $total_pages && $current_page > $start_page + $pages_to_left) {
    $start_page = $current_page - $pages_to_left;
}

/* show next pages to the right */
if ($current_page <= $total_pages && $current_page > $start_page - $pages_to_right) {
    $end_page = $current_page + $pages_to_right;
    if ($current_page == $total_pages || $current_page + 1 == $total_pages || $current_page + 2 == $total_pages || $current_page + 3 == $total_pages) {
        $end_page = $total_pages;
    }
} else {
    $end_page = $total_pages;
}

/* show previous button */
if ($current_page > 1) {
    echo '<a href="?page='.$previous.'">&laquo;</a>';
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}

/* display pages */
for ($page = $start_page; $page <= $end_page; $page++) {
    echo '<a href="?page='.$page.'">'.$page.'</a>';
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}

/* show last page button */
if ($end_page + $pages_to_right <= $total_pages || $end_page != $total_pages) {
    echo '<a href="?page='.$total_pages.'">&hellip;' . $total_pages . '</a>';
}

/* show next button */
if ($current_page < $total_pages) {
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo '<a href="?page='.$next.'">&raquo;</a>';
}
```

Here is a pastebin link to the script: https://pastebin.com/espTvimy

Kindly check it out and let me know if it works for you.