# How to add pagination Using PHP?

Tags: php, pagination

I am using a API , I have access to the current page URL and the final page URL ,

I get current page URL by $page , and Final page URL by $total ,

I get the next page by $page + 1 ,

I need to display the post navigator as

```
<< 1 2 3 4 5 .... 190 >>
```

Assuming 190 as the final page ,

The problem is that When I reach the page 190 , the pagination show `<< 190 191 192 193 194 ... 190 >>`

How can this be fixed as 190 is the final page , I need to display pages before it , and also disable the >> next ,

Same In case of Page 1 , I need to disable << button ...

All the page data is served using $_GET requests , so all pages are same ... No seperate home page or ending page ...

Comment: Possibly, this will help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40069769/7832155

Comment: Always post your latest/best code with your question.

Comment: What you have tried so far??,we are not here to solve your problems from ground level ,update questions with code samples

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate start page, end page and iterate over them.

For example, for the first page you should start from 1 till 5, but as 5 is less, then maximal page (190), you should add "..." and 190. However, because start page is 1, you should not allow "<<" link.

If you are on a page 190, the end page could be 190 + 5 = 195. However the maximum page is 190, set is as a end page. So, the start page will be end page - 5: 190 - 5 = 185. Because your end page is the maximal page, disable ">>" link. Because 185 is more than 1, you could add "..." and 1.

Everything other is just a small details of an algorithm for better look.

Answer (score 0):

You should just check if the $page == $total then subtract the $page by 1 I assume that you are using while loop or for loop for iterating it . And there should be also a terminating condition like while $page >=1. 
You just have to use loop and conditions to solve your problem.
Ex. psuedocode

```
$page = 200; // getting it by extracting the get request
$total = 200;
while($page >= $limit) //$limit can be defined by you upto which you want to iterate.
{
$page = $page - 1;//echo it in html
 }
```